# Using Regex to Search for HTML links near keywords

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

If I'm looking for the keyword "sales" and I want to get the nearest "http://www.somewebsite.com" even if there is multiple links in the file.  I want the nearest link not the first link.  This means I need to search for the link that comes just before the keyword match.

This doesn't work...

`regex = (http|https)://[-A-Za-z0-9./]+.*(?!((http|https)://[-A-Za-z0-9./]+))sales
sales`

Whats the best way to find a link that is closest to a keyword?

Comment: Please test your code with ... if it works let me know... I'm kinda curious... somestring = "hey whats up... http://www.firstlink.com some other test http://www.secondlink.com then mykeyword"
    keyword = "mykeyword"

Comment: Its better to search for relationships within each page.  If others have ideas on this please let me know!  :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested out this code and it seems to be working...

```
def closesturl(keyword, website):
    keylist = []
    urllist = []
    closest = []
    urls = []
    urlregex = "(http|https)://[-A-Za-z0-9\\./]+"
    urlmatches = re.finditer(urlregex, website, re.IGNORECASE)
    keymatches = re.finditer(keyword, website, re.IGNORECASE)
    for n in keymatches:
        keylist.append([n.start(), n.end()])
    if(len(keylist) > 0):
        for m in urlmatches:
            urllist.append([m.start(), m.end()])
    if((len(keylist) > 0) and (len(urllist) > 0)):
        for i in range (0, len(keylist)):
            closest.append([abs(urllist[0][0]-keylist[i][0])])
            urls.append(website[urllist[0][0]:urllist[0][1]])
            if(len(urllist) >= 1):
                for j in range (1, len(urllist)):
                    if((abs(urllist[j][0]-keylist[i][0]) < closest[i])):
                        closest[i] = abs(keylist[i][0]-urllist[j][0])
                        urls[i] = website[urllist[j][0]:urllist[j][1]]
                        if((abs(urllist[j][0]-keylist[i][0]) > closest[i])):
                            break # local minimum / inflection point break from url list                                                      
    if((len(keylist) > 0) and (len(urllist) > 0)):
        return urls #return website[urllist[index[0]][0]:urllist[index[0]][1]]                                                                
    else:
        return ""

    somestring = "hey whats up... http://www.firstlink.com some other test http://www.secondlink.com then mykeyword"
    keyword = "mykeyword"
    print closesturl(keyword, somestring)
```

The above when run shows... `http://www.secondlink.com`.

If someones got ideas on how to speed up this code that would be awesome!

Thanks
V$H.

Comment: In general it's not a great idea to use regular expressions to parse HTML, although they may be reliable for very simple tasks. See this (famous!) answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/342327

Comment: -1 (after reading the "famous answer"... who can be left unchanged??)

Answer (score 3):

It is generally much easier and more robust to use an HTML parser rather than regex.

Using the third-party module [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/):

```
import lxml.html as LH

content = '''<html><a href="http://www.not-this-one.com"></a>
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.com"></a><p>other stuff</p><p>sales</p>
</html>
'''

doc = LH.fromstring(content)    
for url in doc.xpath('''
    //*[contains(text(),"sales")]
    /preceding::*[starts-with(@href,"http")][1]/@href'''):
    print(url)
```

yields

```
http://www.somewebsite.com
```

---

I find lxml (and XPath) a convenient way to express what elements I'm looking for. However, if installing a third-party module is not an option, you could also accomplish this particular job with [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser) from the standard library:

```
import HTMLParser
import contextlib

class MyParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.last_link = None

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        attrs = dict(attrs)
        if 'href' in attrs:
            self.last_link = attrs['href']

content = '''<html><a href="http://www.not-this-one.com"></a>
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.com"></a><p>other stuff</p><p>sales</p>
</html>
'''

idx = content.find('sales')

with contextlib.closing(MyParser()) as parser:
    parser.feed(content[:idx])
    print(parser.last_link)
```

---

Regarding the XPath used in the lxml solution: The XPath has the following meaning:

```
 //*                              # Find all elements
   [contains(text(),"sales")]     # whose text content contains "sales"
   /preceding::*                  # search the preceding elements 
     [starts-with(@href,"http")]  # such that it has an href attribute that starts with "http"
       [1]                        # select the first such <a> tag only
         /@href                   # return the value of the href attribute
```

Comment: Ok, let me test this out and see if it works... I didn't realize python had such a library.

Comment: I'm looking for something that doesn't involve the use of some non-python standard library.  I'll look into it but this isn't really what I need is it?

Comment: An HTML/XML parser and XPATH are definitely the way to go if you're going to keep working with (extracting data from) HTML/XML.

Comment: @VSH please PLEASE don't do this with regex PLEASE. It's awful, and you're going to make a mistake. See the earlier comment for a good example of why not. There are plenty of other libraries if you have something against lxml.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this one with regex alone (especially looking before the keyword match) as it has no sense of comparing distances.

I think you're best off doing something like this:

- find all occurences of `sales` & get substring index, called `salesIndex`
- find all occurences of `https?://[-A-Za-z0-9./]+` and get the substring index, called `urlIndex`
- loop through `salesIndex`. For each location `i` in `salesIndex`, find the `urlIndex` closest.

Depending on how you want to judge "closest" you may need to get the start *and* end indices of the `sales` and `http...` occurences to compare. i.e., find the end index of a URL that is closest to the start index of the current occurence of `sales`, and find the start index of a URL that is closest to the end index of the current occurence of `sales`, and pick the one that is closer.

You can use `matches = re.finditer(pattern,string,re.IGNORECASE)` to get a list of matches, and then `match.span()` to get the start/end substring indices for each `match` in `matches`.

Comment: This is what I may do.  I prefer something where I can use regex or do a regex look behind.  I may have to store the integer position of all the links and compare those to the indexes of the keyword matches.  Yuck.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what mathematical.coffee suggested, you could try something along these lines:

```
import re
myString = "" ## the string you want to search

link_matches = re.finditer('(http|https)://[-A-Za-z0-9./]+',myString,re.IGNORECASE)
sales_matches = re.finditer('sales',myString,re.IGNORECASE)

link_locations = []

for match in link_matches:
    link_locations.append([match.span(),match.group()])

for match in sales_matches:
    match_loc = match.span()
    distances = []
    for link_loc in link_locations:
        if match_loc[0] > link_loc[0][1]: ## if the link is behind your keyword
            ## append the distance between the END of the keyword and the START of the link
            distances.append(match_loc[0] - link_loc[0][1])
        else:
            ## append the distance between the END of the link and the START of the keyword
            distances.append(link_loc[0][0] - match_loc[1])

    for d in range(0,len(distances)-1):
        if distances[d] == min(distances):
            print ("Closest Link: " + link_locations[d][1] + "\n")
            break
```

Comment: let me look over this code carefully.  It looks like this maybe correct.  I'm just worried about doing a lot of indexing of links that maybe are not needed.  However, the truth is I never really know how far a link is from a keyword match pair.